# Do we still run into Burali-Forti paradox even if we use Zermelo's definition of ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Will we still have Burali-Forti paradox if we use Zermelo's definition of ordinals instead of the Von Neuman's definition?
Because I think when we define the ordinals as {}, {{}}, {{{}}}, ... (using Zermelo's definition) then the set of ordinals which is { {}, {{}}, {{{}}}, ... } can not contain itself by definition hence prevents the paradox.
If I am correct then what is it about Von Neuman's definition that raises Burali-Forti paradox?

Comment: Those were once used as a definition for *naturals*, but also for *ordinals*?

Comment: @ Hagen Can't we use Zermelo's definition as the definition of ordinals?

Comment: You can use that as teh definition of hypre-gizmos if you like, but if youwant to use it as definition of ordinal, the question is: What desirable properties of ordinals would that definition convey? Apparently, Zermelo used a definition very similar to von Neumann's in 1915 (google finds), the idea being that each ordinal is the set of all smaller ordinals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the Burali-Forti paradox is that there is no largest well-ordered set.

Simply because if there is such a set, then by collecting all the initial segments of such a well-ordering (including the set itself), we obtain a well-ordering which is strictly longer, by one point to be precise, and thus we get a contradiction to the maximality of the order.

The actual definition of an ordinal is irrelevant. We just need to be able to run the basic comparison argument on well-orders (i.e. given two well-ordered sets, one of them is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other), and that given a linearly ordered set, we can form the set of its initial segments.

Of course, using the full power of $\sf ZF$, we don't care about arbitrary well-orders, just about the ordinals, so the paradox is seemingly about the class of ordinals. But it really isn't, it's a paradox about having a largest well-ordered set. Just like Cantor's paradox is about having a largest cardinal.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Zermelo's definition only works for finite ordinals - what should $\omega$ be? "$\{\{\{\{...\}\}\}\}$" isn't a set (think about the axiom of foundation). Burali-Forti works because we can prove that the set of ordinals (assuming it exists) is an ordinal; this fails for Zermelo ordinals.

Comment: Well, Zermelo's theory did not have Foundation...

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's still no good notion of infinite Zermelo ordinal, so far as I know, even without Foundation.

Comment: Of course. I was just nitpicking. :)

Comment: @Noah Thanks for the answer. It made it more clear for me complementing Asaf's answer.

Comment: One remark that perhaps should be given, is that even if you take into considering *this* encoding, Zermelo's axiom of infinity required there is a set whose elements are the natural numbers. This is not $\{\{\ldots\}\}$, but rather $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\},\ldots\}$. One could argue that *this* can represent $\omega$. Indeed, there is no easy way to axiomatize the $<$  membership of this coding using $\in$, and the only reasonable way goes through transitive closures which give us the von Neumann ordinals already.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes - and even before that, building $\omega$ in that way is  already in the von Neumann spirit.

Comment: Why wouldn’t taking unions of previous ordinals at limits-make a good notion of zermelo ordinals?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku It's not in the Zermelian spirit since it gives up the idea of an ordinal being a singleton; it's generally a bit ugly since it lacks a single theme for both successor and limit ordinals; and finally, it's just painful to actually use (e.g. think about how hard it is to define $\le$ in the Zermelian setting, especially without using VNian ideas for shortcuts).

Comment: Agreed, what is VNian? Using ideas from the theory of well orderings?

Comment: Cause using transfinite induction on well orderings one can define the order on Zermelo ordinals.

Comment: Perhaps you mean Von-Neumann by VNian?  @NoahSchweber